# Inserting data from a WPF form into a MySQL database via C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, ado.net, mysql-connector

I'm having a peculiar problem with inserting values into a MySQL database via C#.

I have four controls that I am gathering data from in a WPF form; three are textboxes and one is a datepicker.

After connecting to the database, one fills out the form. I have been using the following values:

```
txtIdNumber: 1
dtpDateOfBirth = 7/30/2013 (today)
txtMenarcheAge = 14
txtSport1 = Soccer
```

Here's the code it's being washed through:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to submit these changes to the database? Just making sure...", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                //database logic HERE.
                DateTime birthday = (DateTime)dtpDateOfBirth.SelectedDate;
                string birthdayString = birthday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dtpDateOfBirth.SelectedDate));

                //check each box that MUST contain an entry, then submit it to the database if it's correct
                if (txtIdNumber.Text != "" && dtpDateOfBirth.SelectedDate != null)
                {                        
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestSubject VALUES(NULL, @subjectId, @subjectDOB)";
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectId", txtIdNumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectDOB", "'" + birthdayString + "'");
                    Console.WriteLine(birthdayString);
                    Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@subjectId"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@subjectDOB"].Value);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else if (txtIdNumber.Text != "" && dtpDateOfBirth.SelectedDate != null && txtMenarcheAge.Text != "")
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestSubject VALUES(@subjectId, @subjectDOB, @subjectMenarche)";
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectId", txtIdNumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectDOB", birthdayString);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectMenarche", txtMenarcheAge.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

First, I convert the datetime from the datepicker into something resembling what MySQL uses. Then, I convert it to a string.

Next, I set up the requisite `MySqlCommand` object, and set its `Connection` property to `conn`, which was established in another class.

After that are checks to make sure the form is valid. An ID number for the test subject and a birthday *must* be provided, so they're checked first. This is where we run into trouble. I am relatively new to prepared statements in MySQL, so I used [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html) example in order to get myself oriented. At the block

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestSubject VALUES(NULL, @subjectId, @subjectDOB)";
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectId", txtIdNumber.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectDOB", "'" + birthdayString + "'");
Console.WriteLine(birthdayString);
Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@subjectId"].Value);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I encounter the following exception at runtime:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled


HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Column 'subjectId' cannot be null
  Source=MySql.Data
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Number=1048
  StackTrace:
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at mu_kinect_project_data_form.MainWindow.btnSubmitWholeForm_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\asm3kf.TIGERS\Documents\mu_kinect_project_data_form\mu_kinect_project_data_form\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 315
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at mu_kinect_project_data_form.App.Main() in c:\Users\asm3kf.TIGERS\Documents\mu_kinect_project_data_form\mu_kinect_project_data_form\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I'm not sure where it gets the idea that `subjectId` is `null`. It's receiving input alright.

EDIT: Adding MySQL script, because that's half the puzzle pieces.

```sql
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `kinect7` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `kinect7` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kinect7`.`TestSubject`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kinect7`.`TestSubject` (
  `subjectId` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `subjectDOB` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `subjectMenarche` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subjectId`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `subjectId_UNIQUE` (`subjectId` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '     ';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kinect7`.`SubjectInjury`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kinect7`.`SubjectInjury` (
  `injuryDate` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `injuryKnee` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `TestSubject_subjectId` INT(11) NOT NULL ,  
  `surgeryPerformed` VARCHAR(10) NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`TestSubject_subjectId`, `injuryKnee`, `injuryDate`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PreviousInjury_TestSubject1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TestSubject_subjectId` )
    REFERENCES `kinect7`.`TestSubject` (`subjectId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kinect7`.`SubjectJumps`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kinect7`.`SubjectJumps` (
  `jumpDate` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `rightAnkleRatio` DECIMAL(6,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `leftAnkleRatio` DECIMAL(6,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `rightKneeValgus` DECIMAL(6,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `leftKneeValgus` DECIMAL(6,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `rightKneeFlexion` DECIMAL(6,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `leftKneeFlexion` DECIMAL(6,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `testSubject_subjectId` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jumpDate`, `testSubject_subjectId`) ,
  INDEX `fk_subjectJumps_testSubject_idx` (`testSubject_subjectId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subjectJumps_testSubject`
    FOREIGN KEY (`testSubject_subjectId` )
    REFERENCES `kinect7`.`TestSubject` (`subjectId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kinect7`.`SubjectSports`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kinect7`.`SubjectSports` (
  `sport` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  `TestSubject_subjectId` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TestSubject_subjectId`, `sport`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SubjectSports_TestSubject1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TestSubject_subjectId` )
    REFERENCES `kinect7`.`TestSubject` (`subjectId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;   

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: What's your table layout? You're inserting SubjectId and DOB into different columns in those two statements. In one, SubjectId is the second column and in the other it's the first column. My guess is your first column is subjectId and the null you're inserting is causing the error.

Comment: Sorry, was actually trying to get it in the post when you guys asked... thanks error checker... >:/

Comment: 1 - Remove all this code from code behind and create a proper ViewModel. 2 - Use an ORM and forget all this SQL string mess.

Comment: Yes, so as I speculated, that's your problem. subjectId is column1 and you're inserting a hard-coded null into it. If you follow Will Eddin's advice, you'll avoid that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to figure out where exactly your error is occuring, but you may want to define your column names in your SQL query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestSubject (Subject,DOB) VALUES (@subjectId, @subjectDOB)";
```

This way, you don't have to explicitly pass in null for a missing column, and you're sure which columns each value are getting assigned to.

Comment: That works, so far. Let me do some quick checks to see if the values match up correctly. 

Shows you what happens when you follow instructions... thanks Oracle!